# Verifying username match from outside API during the registration process

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, basic-authentication

I am making a web application that allows Fortnite players to find other players to play with. Users should be able to register, login, post and comment. I have designed the frontend portion of the user login and registration features as well as the backend of the user registration but one of my requirements is that:

Before registration, the server should check whether the username provided is a real Fortnite username using the FortniteTracker API which provides user profiles using their very simple API.

Example Call: GET https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}

How do I verify the username exists before allowing the user to create the account?

I have tried creating a separate endpoint for the API call from the server side but I didn't know how to implement it into my /register endpoint

script.js

```
function registerRequest(username,password) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/register",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({username,password}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    error : function(err) {
      console.log('Error here!', err)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Success!')
      // What do I put here?
    }
  });
}


function handleRegisterSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const username = $(event.currentTarget).find('.username-register').val()
  const password = $(event.currentTarget).find('.password-register').val()
  const passwordConfirm = $(event.currentTarget).find('.password-confirm').val()

  if (password === passwordConfirm) {
    registerRequest(username,password)
  }
  else {
    console.error("Passwords did not match")
  }

}

$(function onLoad() {
    displayRegisterPage()
    $(`.js-content-section`).on('submit', '.js-register-form', handleRegisterSubmit)
  }

})
```

server.js

```
app.post('/register', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  const requiredFields = ['username', 'password']
  for (let i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i++) {
    const field = requiredFields[i]
    if (!(field in req.body)) {
      const message =  `Missing \`${field}\` in request body`
      console.error(message)
      return res.status(400).send(message)
    }
  }
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  User.findOne({username})
  .then(user => {
    if (user) {
      const message = `username is already taken`
      console.error(message)
      return res.status(400).send(message)
    }
    else {
      User.create({username, password})
      .then(user => {
        const userRes = {
          id: user._id,
          username: user.username
        }

        res.status(201).json(userRes)
      }
      )
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went horribly wrong'})
  })

})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  const usernameReq = User.findById(req.body.username);
  if (usernameReq) {
    console.log(usernameReq)
    res.status(201).json(usernameReq)
  }
})
```

schema.js

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I expect that if I register with "ninja" as a username I should be able to register since that is a valid Fortnite username. The actual output currently allows users to register with any username that isnt already taken in the database.

Comment: What seems to be the issue here? You could easily add the code to make an API call to tracker API from your register API's handler and if it is valid proceed with registration, else send a response saying it is not a valid username.

Comment: how do I do that? I'm not sure where to put it

Comment: right after basic field check is done and before you check in database using `User.findOne()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by sending the username to the API [https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}](https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/%7Bplatform%7D/%7Bepic-nickname%7D)

It will give you a response mentioning about the user exists or not. Based on the response you can make another AJAX request to register the user only if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You would need packages like `axios`, `request`, `request-promise` (`Promise` supported version of `request`) etc to make the external api call. You can try implementing within the `register` like.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

app.post('/register', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  ...
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;

  const options = {
    method : 'GET',
    uri: 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }
  const data = await rp(options)
  // check if response code is 200 and check for the expected body
  ...
  // continue rest of the code
}
```

Or have another middleware to call the external endpoint and do the checks like:

```
async function checkUser (req, res, next) {
  const options = {
    method : 'GET',
    uri: 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }
  const data = await rp(options)
  // check if response code is 200 and check for the expected body
  if (checks ok)
    // if all check ok go to next middleware
    next()
  else
    // if checks did not succeed
    // you could pass error to error handler like next(new Error("Hey you do not exist"))
    // or render something here
}
```

Then mount it like:

```
app.post('/register', jsonParser, checkUser, (req, res) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a Promise request to resolve, reject when someone enters their username. It is only called onClick. in your request you will be able to determine if the call was successfull or not with the username.